# adding health check to docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, health-check

I am trying to add a health check to my docker container so in my Dockerfile I added this line

`HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8080/health || exit 1`

based loosely on this tutorial: https://howchoo.com/g/zwjhogrkywe/how-to-add-a-health-check-to-your-docker-container . In my docker-compose file I have added the health check line like this:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--silent", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
```

but the container always reports unhealthy. So if I execute `docker exec -it my-container /bin/bash` and get inside the container and then execute the health request I get this:

```
    $ curl --fail http://localhost:8080/health
    curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 411 Length Required
```

What am I missing? Nginx is already installed in the container so I would like to simply make that URL with `/health` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave up on using the `HEALTHCHECK` command in `Dockerfile` and instead I am changing the `nginx.conf` file by adding

```
    location /health {
        access_log off;
        return 200 "healthy\n";
    }
```

`docker-compose.yml` remains the same.
This works well enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach, correlating a port being listened on with a healthy status.

`netcat` is installed by default in Alpine Linux

```yaml
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-vz", "-w1", "localhost", "80"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 30
```

This will exit with status 0 if port `80` is open.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you can use the following example -
[How to Add a Health Check to Your Docker Container](https://howchoo.com/devops/how-to-add-a-health-check-to-your-docker-container)

There's a minor correction to the Dockerfile they provide though as there's an issue to check the health status (curl had to be installed there as well but let me know if you need any help or have any question).

Please refer to this particular one as a solution -

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /data \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        openssl \
        curl \
        dumb-init \
        postgresql-libs \
        ca-certificates

#CMD apt-get install curl

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -f http://localhost:5000/ || exit 1

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```